# Using database on another development machine

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an ASP.NET website. I wanted to shift whole of my work to another PC of mine. I copied the website to the other PC>Open>Create ASP.NET folder>App_Data

and pasted the database.mdf and database.ldf files there. I was getting some exception when I was trying to run the website as it showed the "could not open the connection from `con.open()`". Is there some other step too that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server database files are not like any simple html files that can be copied between machines. You need to make sure that the database that is getting served up: e.g. there is a Sql Server instance running that can present the database to your web application.

Here's an article on [how to attach an mdf file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) to a Sql Server.

Comment: But while detaching, the database can be copied directly from `Program Fies>Microsoft SQL Server>MSSQL 1.0>MSSQL>Data>.mdf` directly, right? It's not necessary to detach it using Management Studio. From the computer I copied the mdf, it didn't have Management Studio installed.

Comment: Attaching and detaching doesn't have to be done using the Mgmt Studio, that's just a tool. And the fact that you were able to copy it readily makes me think it wasn't attached or running at the time. In any case, you do need to attach the mdf/lfd files to the Sql Server instance with T-SQL or via Mgmt Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the mdf and ldf files to the sql server instance on the target machine. You may need to adjust your connection string as well, unless you used a local name reference like "." for the data source.

Comment: I checked the connection string already but I didn't attach the database to the SQL Server. Another questions related to this that arises to my mind is that if I have to upload the database to my host, then uploading this using ftp to App_Data won't be enough, I would still have to changed some things?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid so. You'll either need the host to attach it, or if you have sufficient access, attach it yourself, OR, and some hosts like it this way, generate a sql script that they can run to generate the db.

Comment: But in either case, your host probably deals with this all the time. You might just ask which method they prefer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What is your connection string? Chances are the path in the connection string has the local path to the database file on your original development machine.